# Failed to load resource(Images): the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, express, proxy

[I was trying to connect express to the frontend react application. The images when I used to start the react where visible, but when I used proxy of express in my frontend JSON file the images stopped showing all of the sudden and said images not found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0ZZ7.png)

[This is my server.js code, if it needs any changes then let me know.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL1hF.png)[Proxy code is also shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bLKI.png)[Images I put using both URL method and regular method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQy9p.png)

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular the part about posting actual code here and not *images* of code.